# The Lebesgue Monotone Convergence theorem on function domains

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, volume

I am trying to prove an analogous statement of the Lebesgue Monotone Convergence theorem on function domains.

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded set that has volume. Let $f : A \mapsto \mathbb{R}, f \ge 0$ be an unbounded function. Suppose $C_i$ is a sequence of compact sets with volume, $C_i \subset A$ with $C_i$ increasing to $A$. Then $f$ is integrable iff $f$ is integrable on each $C_i, \lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{C_i} f$ exists, and $\int_A f = \lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{C_i} f$.

This is intuitively clear. If $f$ is integrable on each $C_i$ and $\lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{C_i} f = I$, then I should be able to find $N_1, N_2$ such that $vol(A)-vol(C_i) < \epsilon$ if $i > N_1$ and $|\int_{C_i} f - I| < \epsilon$ if $i > N_2$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Then take $N = max\{N_1,N_2\}$, I should be able to show $f$ is integrable and $|\int_A f - I| < \epsilon$. But I got stuck in trying to work out the details of partitions.

Conversely, if $f$ is integrable, I should be able to apply Darboux's theorem and show that $|\int_{C_i} f - \int_A f| < \epsilon$. But I think Darboux's theorem only applies to bounded functions, and I don't know that how to use the condition that each $C_i$ is compact. It would be nice if $f$ is continuous, then $f$ would be bounded on each $C_i$, but the proposition does not mention this either. Can someone help with these details or give me a hint? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_i=f\chi_{C_i}$. Then $(f_i)$ is a sequence of non-negative measurable functions increasing to $f$. By Lebesgue's Monotone convergence Theorem $\int_A f=\lim \int_A f_i=\lim \int_{C_I} f$ (and this does not require any further hypothesis like integrability, boundedness etc). The conclusion follows immediately from this.

Comment: This is such an intelligent way of solving my problem! Thank you very much! Does this prove both sides of the argument?

Comment: Yes, it does prove that $f$ is integrable if and only if it is integrable on each $C_i$ and $\lim \int_{C_i} f$ exists and is finite (with $\int_A f$ equal to this limit). @InsultedByMathematics

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on where you implicitly used the condition that each $C_i$ s compact?

Comment: No need for compactness. All you need is the fact that $C_i$'s are Borel sets increasing to $A$.  @InsultedByMathematics

Comment: I see. It seems that that condition is there to confuse people.

Comment: I think in order for Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence theorem to apply, I need both $f$ and $f_i$ to be integrable. Now, $f_i$ is integrable if $f$ is integrable since each $C_i$ has volume and therefore its boundary has measure zero. But I am not sure how I can prove $f$ is integrable if $f_i$ is integrable. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Integrability is not at all required for MCT. Even if all the intergrals are equal to $+\infty$ the theorem is valid. Allowing functions and integrals to be $\infty$ is one of the main advantages of measure theory (as compared to basic Calculus). @InsultedByMathematics

Comment: I see. I think MCT justifies $\int_A f = \lim\int_{C_i} f$, but does not justify $f$ is integrable iff $f$ is integrable on each $C_i$, which is part of the statement I am trying to prove. I think the condition that each $C_i$ is compact might be of use there.

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics $\int_{C_i} f \leq \int_A f$ so $f$ is integrable on each $C_i$ if it is integrable . On the other hand  if $f$ is integrable on each $C_i$ and $\int_{C_i} f$ has  a finite limit then $\int f$ is equal to this limit, so $f$ is integrable. No compactness or any topological ideas are needed (except for the fact that compact sets are measurable sets).

Comment: I see! Thank you very much! This answers all my questions.